# responsive grid, 3 columns with multiple lines

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am currently using the following code to display a grid of images.

The problem is that when you gradually reduce the width of the browser, the grid will switch straight from 3 columns layout to 1 column layout.

How can i make it so the grid also switch to 2 columns layout before going to the 1 column layout, for middle sized tablets screens and such ?

Live demo: https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/test2.php

```
<style>
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 100%; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 66.66%; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 33.33%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
    .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}
</style>


<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style=\"min-width:200px\">
    .........................................
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style=\"min-width:200px\">
    .........................................
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style=\"min-width:200px\">
    .........................................
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style=\"min-width:200px\">
    .........................................
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style=\"min-width:200px\">
    .........................................
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style=\"min-width:200px\">
    .........................................
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it ain't broke don't fix it. It seems to work fine without, but idk

Comment: Also, I would advise using flexbox. Take a look at this pen of mine: http://codepen.io/Thallon/pen/pJZZXy

Comment: i need the 2 rows layout

Comment: something like in the codepen link, but with fixed image size

Comment: The images in the demo are a fixed 400x400 size

Comment: With small browser width it resizes the images. I also need a grid system where i can insert more than just images

Comment: I need to convert this into responsive grid: http://gyazo.com/8ca641f5e83cfecef468a564dd7c0cf7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83643/discussion-between-speedyninja-and-libertaire).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another breakpoint for tablet view. e.g.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 480px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .span_3_of_3, 
    .span_2_of_3, 
    .span_1_of_3 { 
       width: 50%; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will just change the width, i need 2 columns layout